# Find an equivalent to $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^{2}}$ when ${n \rightarrow \infty}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Find an equivalent to $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^{2}}$ when ${n \rightarrow \infty}$

With Stirling's approximation, is it $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$?

Comment: The fraction represents the probability of picking a subset of length n from the power set of 2n objects. Does that fact help?

Comment: It helps. The problem is what the high order items behave like.

Comment: The issue is that you are saying "limit" : the limit of your expression is indeed $0$ whereas you should use the term "equivalent". This is not at all the same thing. You should modify your title accordingly ("find an equivalent to...")

Comment: Keyword "Central binomial coefficient" provides you many answers, for example https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/c/c178.htm, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html

Comment: @Jean Marie You are right. I am sorry that I do not find a way to modify my title. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have done it for you.

Comment: @Jean Marie Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have [these estimates for the central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) for $n\ge1$:
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{4n}} \leq {2n \choose n} \leq \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{3n+1}}
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^{2}}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stirling approximation such that:

$$\lim_{n \to ∞}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}}$$$$=\lim_{n \to ∞}\frac{2\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^{2n}\left(2\pi n\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^{2n}$$$$=\lim_{n \to ∞}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{\left(\pi n\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{2n}{2e}\cdot\frac{e}{n}\right)^{2n}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\pi}\lim_{n \to ∞}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=0$$